# Export 3D model from Blender to .U3D for use in PDF file

Tags: export, file-format

.pdf files supports [Displaying 3D models](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/displaying-3d-models-pdfs.html), you can view the model from any angle by mouse movements - sort of like looking through the viewport, only the object is fully rendered, "real", etc. This requires a .ud3 file. Blender does not export a .ud3 file. Any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: .pdf need the 3d model to be in .u3d format so you should use a plugin to export your model to .u3d or use intermediate software . check this [thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261646-U3D-Exporter)

Comment: Thread very helpful. I would add to several requests for a .py plug in for Blender that would allow an export of a .ud3 file. This .ude can be inserted into .pdf files..., great for product demos, portfolios, etc.

Comment: did you confirm that the BlenderToU3D plug-in is not working properly?

Comment: Well I tried to. Installed ok. Hit Export .ud3 and in the top info box in Blender is a quick message: "The exporter is accessed through the scene buttons. Please head there to use it." which left me baffled. Where are the scene buttons and what should I look for?

Comment: I'm going to try it

Comment: I'd like to revive this topic. Chebhou did you ever try this? If so, what happened?

Comment: as I recall it didn't work at that time but not sure about the details now ( edit your question to get attention  from other users)

Answer (score -1):

You can find the scene button in the property Area, scroll down to find the u3d export.
I managed to export to u3d, but after putting it to pdf with latex the pdf failed to open correctly in adobe reader XI. a "3D data parsing error has occurred"

[image: properties area with scene button and u3d export]

Comment: So, it actually did not work? And where to get the plugin?