# How do i export a blender animation to a 3d pdf?

Tags: animation, export

Is there any way to export an animation made with blender to a 3d PDF?

I have several objects (up to 30) in my blender file. I set two keyframes (at 0 and 250), so that every object has two positions. The animation moves every object from start to end position. The objects have no textures. First, i only need to export that objects and their animated moving to the 3d PDF. I want to transfer the information of the blender-animation to the 3d PDF! It should not be just a static 3d model.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I for one have never use the 3D capabilities of a pdf, so I have no idea what a pdf is expecting in terms of file type.

Comment: it seems a specific format (and tools) is needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_3D see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24648/export-3d-model-from-blender-to-u3d-for-use-in-pdf-file